# Selenium Java - - RemoteWebDriver Error/exception

Tags: java, selenium, remotewebdriver

java version: 1.8

selenium version: latest as of april 2017

Hub/grid has been set up on a different machine which is a ec2 windows instance. A node successfully registers.

No erros on hub and node consoles. I can see the console on the browser with the registered node and browsers exposed.

`java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\selenium_grid\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub -host <ipaddress> -port 4444`

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -port 5555 -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=opera,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=safari,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=internet explorer,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS"`

---

`webdriver = new RemoteWebDriver(seleniumGridURL, desiredCapabilities);`

`public enum DriverType implements DriverSetup {`

```
FIREFOX {
    public DesiredCapabilities getDesiredCapabilities(Proxy proxySettings) {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        return addProxySettings(capabilities, proxySettings);
    }

    public WebDriver getWebDriverObject(DesiredCapabilities capabilities) {
        return new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    }
}}`
```

---

**Error:**
`driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:174)
    at com.website.selenium.config.DriverFactory.instantiateWebDriver(DriverFactory.java:86)
    at com.website.selenium.config.DriverFactory.getDriver(DriverFactory.java:42)
    at com.website.selenium.DriverBase.getDriver(DriverBase.java:34)
    at com.website.selenium.listeners.ScreenshotListener.onTestFailure(ScreenshotListener.java:51)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1699)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:703)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
Unable to parse remote response: Cannot POST /wd/hub/session`

Trying to enable debug as suggested:
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -debug -log c:\selenium_grid\grid.log -role node -port 5555 -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=opera,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=safari,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=internet explorer,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS"`

`Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: "-debug": couldn't convert "-log" to a boolean`

Comment: How are the hug and node started? What do the node and hub logs show?

Comment: @MarkLapierre I have updated the question above. I dont see any errors regarding those

Comment: Try with logging and debugging enabled on the node `-debug -log path/to/log/file`

Comment: @MarkLapierre Updated my results. couldnt get it to work :-(

Comment: Sorry, it seems the syntax has changed since I last used it. It now expects `debug` to take a boolean param. So it should be `-debug true`

Comment: I have the debug on now. Im following the guidelines from this project: https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template

Comment: What do the logs show when that error occurs? In particular, the node log should show "Cannot POST /wd/hub/session" as well.

Comment: Thanks for responses @MarkLapierre. This was a networking issue with aws VPC's and private IP's. It is resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a networking issue with aws VPC's and private IP's and opening the TCP and UDP ports in windows firewall + modifying sec groups (incoming ports for windows machine) in the EC2 instance.